How to get the report between certain date range in Cognos per month
I need a report to schedule out every month with the current maturity date associated with that scheduled period. For example, I want to send out a December report with all December current maturites only for that month. Same for January,etc...
[Current Maturity Date] between dateadd({month}, datediff({month}, -2,getdate()) ,1) and dateadd({month}, 0, dateadd({month}, datediff({month}, 0, getdate()) +2,1))
This is delivering for only December right now, but will it do it for January automatically?
